# How To Fix WP Query Returns Results But Shouldn't?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, sql

I have a WP Query that should return no results, but instead seems to be returning items. I'm guessing the null result is being interpreted as "return all results" but I'm not sure the proper fix. It looks like this:

```
    $pairedThing = get_field('myThing');
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'=> 2,
    'post_type'     => 'thing',
    'meta_key'      => 'identifier',
    'meta_value'    => $pairedThing,
    );
    
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <tr><td>Name</td><td>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </td></tr>
    <?php endwhile; else: 
                            //{echo 'None';}
    ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Each query will either have a single result (if there is a match to the query) or no results. When there is a match everything works as planned, but when there is no match the most recent result in the post_type are return, when I would expect nothing to be returns.

Any ideas? I trued the "else" but it didn't work.

Comment: unrelated but there is no cleanup code after this, you have to call `wp_reset_postdata()` after your loop (immediatley after `endwhile;` ) or it will contaminate code that runs afterwards. Also there is no handling for when `get_field` fails or the field isn't present or hasn't been set yet or its value is an object/array/etc

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell I do have the `wp_reset_query();` on the next line, I should have included that. And then if `get_field` is empty, it'll return null and then be handled by the `else` part of this function. Maybe there is a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: it won't be handled by the else part, you'll trigger database queries searching for meta with the value null, `'meta_value'    => null,` doesn't mean it won't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things to consider here:

1.) Try adding the meta query only if the value is present:

```
$pairedThing = get_field('myThing');
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post_type'      => 'thing',    
];
if ( ! empty( $pairedThing ) ) {
    $args['meta_key']   = 'identifier';
    $args['meta_value'] = $pairedThing;
}
```

2.) Account for posts without the meta-key set:

```
$pairedThing = get_field('myThing');
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post_type'      => 'thing',
    'meta_query'     => [
        'my_meta_query' [ // Multiple meta-queries per handle.
            'relation' => 'OR',
            [
                'key'     => 'identifier',
                'value'   => $pairedThing,
                'compare' => '=',
            ],
            [
                'key'     => 'identifier',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ],
        ],
    ]
];
```

Comment: Option 1 worked! I guess the lack of an alternative (in this case ! empty) to the query failing meant it had to produce results. Sort of makes sense?? Thank you!